# Create folder in SharePoint Online without using SharePoint Client Model in C#

Tags: development, sharepoint-online, folder

In C#, I want to create a folder in my SharePoint Online site without using SharePoint client object model.

I am trying to use SharePoint REST APIs and List methods.

I don't want to use `Microsoft.SharePoint.Client` as the use of this DLL requires `SharePoint Client Components` to be installed on the client server.

I have found the [this useful link](http://ronaldlemmen.blogspot.in/2010/04/create-folder-in-sharepoint-using-web.html) to achieve this. 
This works fine for SharePoint On-premise instance, but not for SharePoint Online.

It throws the following error message when run for SharePoint Online

> Server was unable to process request. ---> Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED)).

Is there any way to solve this problem?

Comment: Please refer this link:https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn450841.aspx#bk_FolderCollectionRequestExamples

Comment: Thanks.
I have found the following useful links-
- http://ronaldlemmen.blogspot.in/2010/04/create-folder-in-sharepoint-using-web.html
- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2144780/how-to-create-folder-in-sharepoint-on-specified-url-using-web-services

Answer (score 2):

**Endpoint URI**

```
http://<site url>/_api/web/folders (top-level folders at the root site)

http://<site url>/_api/web/getfolderbyserverrelativeurl('/<folder name>')/folders
```

**Create a folder** (POST request example)

```
executor.executeAsync({
  url: "<app web url>/_api/SP.AppContextSite(@target)/web
    /getfolderbyserverrelativeurl('/Shared Documents/Folder A')/folders
    ?@target='<host web url>'",
  method: "POST",
  body: "{ '__metadata':{ 'type': 'SP.Folder' }, 'ServerRelativeUrl':'Folder B' }",
  headers: {
    "accept": "application/json; odata=verbose",
    "content-type": "application/json; odata=verbose"
  },
  success: successHandler,
  error: errorHandler
});
```

Please refer this [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn450841.aspx#bk_FolderCollectionRequestExamples)

Comment: Thank you. But, I am writing C# (plugin) code and not a JavaScript code.